# How to name the a set of functions which do the same operation but on different types?

Tags: bash

For a framework I'm writing I have to implement matcher functions, like e.g. `equals` (whicl tests for equality and also prints out what was expected to match if it doesn't match).

The problem is I need to implement this for strings as well as integers (and probably arrays) and I don't know how distinguish those functions based on their type. Some ideas are:

1. using some sort of prefix

   ```
   integer_equals '1' '2'
   string_equals '1' '2'
   ```
2. passing the type to the function

   ```
   equals 'integer' '1' '2'
   equals 'string' '1' '2'
   ```
3. separating the prefix with a . (dot)

   ```
   string.equals '1' '2'
   integer.equals '1' '2'
   ```

Which one of these would fit best, i.e. which one would be the most idiomatic one or the least astoninishing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your proposal 1 (string_equals) is the clearest and least surprising.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like in tcl:

```
string equal s1 s2
```

Example of implementation: a function returning status, other implementation is to write output `if [ "$2" = "$3" ];then echo true; else echo false; end` and let the caller egt the output `r=$(string equal a z)`

```
string() {
  case "$1" in
  equal)
    [ "$2" = "$3" ]
    return $?
    ;;
  *)
    echo "'$1' not implemented" >&2
    return 1
    ;;
  esac
}
```

And usage

```
if string equal a a; then echo true; fi
string equal a b; echo $?;   # exit status 0:true, <>0:false
```

Comment: how would that be implemented? something like this would be awesome but I couldn't find a way to implement this.